# Angular mat-form-field not working properly - A border line appears inside the field

Tags: angular, angular-material, tailwind-css

While implementing the angular's material library to make form fields and form fields I am getting this unsual ui issue, where when implemented, a line appears in the form field which should not happen.

UI specifications:

1. TailwindCSS
2. DaisyUI (Component library)
3. Angular Material

**Following is the code that I have written:**

```
<form
        [formGroup]="UserSignUp"
        (ngSubmit)="submitForm()"
        id="sign-in-form"
        onsubmit="return false"
        novalidate
      >
        <div class="form-control w-full">
          <label class="label">
            <span class="label-text font-semibold text-lg">Email</span>
          </label>
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label> Email </mat-label>
            <input
              formControlName="email"
              placeholder="Enter your email..."
              [(ngModel)]="obj.email"
              matInput
            />
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-error
            class="mt-1"
            *ngIf="isSubmitted && errorControl['email'].errors?.['required']"
          >
            Email is required
          </mat-error>
          <mat-error
            class="mt-1"
            *ngIf="isSubmitted && errorControl['email'].errors?.['pattern']"
          >
            Invalid Email structure
          </mat-error>
        </div>
        <a routerLink="/dashboard">
          <button class="bg-primary text-white py-3 w-full rounded-lg">
            Sign Up
          </button>
        </a>
</form>
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatIconModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
```

**What is showing:**
[This the result that is showing, as you can see there is a red line inside the form-field deviding the field into two sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay2tw.png)

**What should be showing:**
[This is the image taken from official docs. As you can see that there is no inner line inside the form-field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcGlh.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Angular Material, there can be a conflict with TailwindCSS styles which may cause some visual issues. One common issue is with the `.mdc-notched-outline__notch` class.

To resolve this, you can override the conflicting style in your `style.scss` file. Add the following CSS rule:

```css
.mdc-notched-outline__notch {
  border-right: none;
}
```

This rule sets the `border-right` property of the `.mdc-notched-outline__notch` class to `none`, effectively removing the right border. This should resolve the conflict with TailwindCSS.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Consider https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/9993

Answer (score 2):

Tailwindcss conflicts with Angular Material css class `mdc-notched-outline__notch`. `border-style: solid` rule is defined in Tailwindcss base.css file. You can solve this problem by overriding the Tailwindcss `border-style: solid`.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, and currently don't know why.
I found that there is something wrong with the mat label.
But I did manage to eliminate the unexpected border using scss for a while.

```
::ng-deep .mdc-notched-outline__notch {
  border-right: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Are you using tailwindcss?  See more recent comments under Mr.Sharp's solution.

Comment: that's right @AdamCox, I use tailwind css and angular material. Thanks for letting me know about other recent comment discussions. I've read the discussion on Github, really explain what happened

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to fix it in the styles.css, after loading tailwind:

```
@tailwind base
@tailwind components
@tailwind utilities

@layer base
  *, ::before, ::after
    border-style: none
```

After that you must set **border-style** in elements that you style with tailwindcss.